# Using wsHttpBinding, WCF is ignoring my web.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF service that requires session support so I added a section in my web.config to enable wsHttpBinding. But when I test the service in the WCF Test Client and check the config it seems to have taken the default auto generated config instead of my own.

See my config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>    
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service name="UserService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ICenterPlaceUserService" />
  </service>
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

And the result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICenterPlaceUserService" sendTimeout="00:05:00" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:57418/L1.WCF/CenterPlaceUserService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICenterPlaceUserService"
            contract="ICenterPlaceUserService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICenterPlaceUserService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: I assume you are adding a Service Reference to your project.  If this is true, did you update the Service Reference in the project afterwards?

Comment: I am not using the service in any project so far. I am using the WCF Test Client that opens automatically when I press Debug from the *.svc.cs file.

Comment: Have you tried saving the project, closing Visual Studio and trying again?

Comment: Yeah I have had that problem for a few days now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `name` attribute of the `<service>` attribute must have the **fully-qualified name** of the service class. Otherwise it will be ignored, and you'll see the behavior you're seeing: the default binding is used for the service (basicHttpBinding).

```
<services>
  <service name="TheNamespaceOfYourClass.UserService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="TheNamespaceOfYourContract.ICenterPlaceUserService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks !